# Google's PlusOne button ironically not showing in Chrome. Why?

Tags: google-plus-one

I had this working before and I just noticed today that my plus one buttons are no longer showing on my pages.  Inspecting them, I see they are at a top and left of -10000px.  I certainly have no styles doing this.  I see others reporting similar issues (usually years ago) but I've yet to find a solution that applies.  (I've confirmed my pages have a *link rel="canonical"* tag. The page isn't https.)

It displays normally in IE, FF, but not chrome or opera.

[A sample page is here](http://smartieparts.com/test/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=295).

[Google's implementation page is here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/?hl=en).

Pretty simple stuff really so I'm not sure what's going wrong.  Any ideas?

edit:  This css hack worked

```
/*fix for Google's f'ed up Google Plus button*/
#___plusone_0, #___plusone_0 iframe {
    position:static !important;
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
```

But obviously I shouldn't have to rely on that.  After digging and reading a bunch, I believe it is simply a bug with Google Chrome.  Absolutely ridiculous that their own product doesn't work in only their browser.

Comment: Some kind of ad blocker maybe?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in the question:  I turned of ALL extensions once I read somewhere that an ad blocker could do it.